# How to correctly add eslint config in turborepo?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, vite, tsconfig, turborepo

I use turborepo with 2 apps (both with vite). I add eslint config to eslint-config-custom and extend it in my apps, but after calling npm install in each app in folder node_modules, creates eslint-config-custom with and add some rules. I don't understand, why it add this rules and no add rules from packages/eslint-config-custom/index.ts. Maybe someone faced such a problem?

1. app structure [image]
2. client/node_modules/eslint-client-custom [image]
3. turbo.json [image]
4. packages/eslint-config-custom/index.ts [image]
5. packages/eslint-config-custom/package.json [image]

Answer (score 0):

The `package.json` that you see in `apps/client/node_modules/eslint-client-custom/package.json` should be just a link to your local `packages/eslint-config-custom/package.json`.

When declaring `eslint-config-custom` as one of the dependencies for your `apps/client`, make sure to list it with `*` as the version.

`apps/client/package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "client",
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-custom": "*"
  }
}
```

I'd recommend deleting `node_modules` and re-running `npm i` after making this change.